# Yii 2: AJAX валидация не Active Form полей

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, yii2

Есть Active Form с 2 полями:

1. `$form->field($model)` -- поле модели, через `ActiveForm::validate($model)` валидируется и отправляется JSON с ошибками.
2. `Html::textInput()` -- никак автоматически не валидируется

И вот вопрос, мы без проблем можем сами проверить поле [2] и даже вернуть JSON в том же формате и теми же данными от Active Form, но в клиентской части, они никак не обрабатываются (конечная верстка поля [2] полностью соответствует полю [1]). Как обработать ошибку и аналогично вывести сообщение?

На странице имеется скрипт `yiiActiveForm` с массивом AF-полей. Возможно туда можно добавить и наше?

Либо приходит на ум написать свой JS скрипт, который будет использовать API `yii.activeForm.js`

Возможно можно как-то одной строчкой добавить наши поля в клиенткий обработчик JSON массива ошибок?

Answer (score 1):

Если своя валидация:

```
ActiveForm::begin([
    'action' => '/process/save',
    'validationUrl' => '/process/validation', ...
```

Есть вариант навесить свой обработчик:

```
$('form').on('ajaxComplete', function (e, attribute, message) {
    if (attribute.responseJSON.delivery !== undefined){ // если ошибка то добавляем сообщение с ней
        $('.title').after('<div class="message-error"><p>'+attribute.responseJSON.delivery+'</p></div>');
    } else if (attribute.responseJSON.delivery === undefined && $('.message-error').text().length > 0) {
      //если всё верно удаляем сообщение с ошибкой
        $('.message-error').remove();
    }

});
```

На сервере в `['/process/validation']` валидируем поле

```
if (!$Delivery->validate()) {
    $this->_errors = ['delivery' => 'Ошибка валидации'];
    throw new BadRequestHttpException();
}
```